# ¿How to read local json files in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

I've read many posts where someone explains how to do it, but in my case, it's not working and I'm not sure why, I've added the right folder to the pubspec.yaml and everything, this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:workout_time/Widgets/routines_widget.dart';

void main() => runApp(WorkoutTime());

class WorkoutTime extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Great App',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RoutinesWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RoutinesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RoutinesWidgetState createState() => _RoutinesWidgetState();
}

class _RoutinesWidgetState extends State<RoutinesWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: rootBundle.loadString("assets/data.json"),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          var myData = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toString());
          return Center(
            child: Text(myData == null ? "Nothing here" : myData),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when I run it, I get the CircularProgressIndicator widget, meaning that the snapshot has no data. Can anyone help me?

Edit: here is the part in the pubspec.yaml where I import the folder:

```
assets:
  - assets/
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

Comment: I think this is going to re-execute the loadString up to 60 times per second: rootBundle.loadString("assets/data.json")... you need to move that out into an initState so that the future is extracted only once, and then completed by the FutureBuilder.

Comment: Yeah, I tried something like that, and didn't work either: 
`Future _data;
  Future<String> loadJson() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString("routines/routine_1.json");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _data = loadJson();
    super.initState();
  }`
and then in the FutureBuilder is the some, just the line `future: _data,` Sorry I can't make a better format

Comment: No.  In initState, _data = rootBundle.loadString("routines/routine_1.json"); , then in build() put _data as your future:.

Comment: Nope, same result :(

Comment: It would be nice for you to provide a smallest reproducible code segment, and also never ever ever type  "it didn't work".  What *did* it do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new at this too, I'll edit the question so it can be used as it is. Thanks for the advice!!

Answer (score 0):

Code - pubspec.yaml

assets:
- assets/json/

Code - In a Class

```
   static Map<dynamic, dynamic> jsonData;
    loadJson() async {
      String jsonContent = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/json/data.json");
      jsonData = json.decode(jsonContent);
    }
```